# Dettol soap halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram

Is dettol soap halal and safe to use?

I've seen that it contains glycerin which is haram if it's obtained from dead meat or pork.

But I've seen that it is made from Indonesia which has the largest muslim population so the glycerin probably derives from halal meat.

Comment: You can see [This video](https://youtu.be/ZnqnT3GoWsA) it explains this topic very well very well. Even thou it talks about other substances but the context and the overall outcome is same.

Comment: That's about alcohol not glycerin. I know alcohol isn't najis but glycerin is najis if it is from haram meat